# pass and set javascript variables as value on a get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do I call a javascript variable to be set as value on my get function?

i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imagelinks = $('div[name=content] a');  
    idno = imagelinks.attr('idno');
</script>
```

and i want idno to be set as value of my input type in a get function. this is the code:

```
<form method="GET" action="action.php">
    <input id="i1" name="i1" value=" //this is where i want "idno" to be passed">
</form>
```

help pls!

Comment: Why don't you set the value on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
$('#i1').val(idno);
```

Comment: Question is not tagged as jQuery

Comment: That's OK, but you could also do everything in one step, upon form submission: `myForm.submit(function() { $('#i1').val($('div[name=content] a').attr('idno')); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imagelinks = $('div[name=content] a');  
idno = imagelinks.attr('idno');
document.getElementById('i1').value = idno;
</script>
```